# Centering a symbol with overset

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, alignment, fontawesome

I'm attempting to center the `\faPiedPiper` symbol over a single letter like so:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome, amsmath, fourier}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\text{\faPiedPiper}}{X}$
\end{document}
```

but I'm getting off-centered spacing as follows
[image: sample output]

What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some trial and error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome,fourier,amsmath,accents}

\newcommand{\fancyhatsymbol}{\text{\normalfont\faPiedPiper}\mspace{-6mu}}
\newcommand{\fancyhat}[1]{\accentset{\fancyhatsymbol}{#1\mspace{2mu}}}

\begin{document}

$\fancyhat{X}$   

\end{document}
```

Note that `\accentset` uses a smaller size than `\overset`.

[image]